# Which Unicode space has the same width as 1ch?

Tags: css, unicode

This are the Unicode [spaces](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm):

- U+0020 SPACE
- U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE
- U+1680 OGHAM SPACE MARK
- U+2000 EN QUAD
- U+2001 EM QUAD
- U+2002 EN SPACE
- U+2003 EM SPACE
- U+2004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE
- U+2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
- U+2006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE
- U+2007 FIGURE SPACE
- U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE
- U+2009 THIN SPACE
- U+200A HAIR SPACE
- U+202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
- U+205F MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
- U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE

Which of them has the same width as `1ch` in CSS?

Comment: Just for fun -- https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/qwpqkLop/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unicode does not guarantee any space character to have the same advance width as U+0030 ZERO, which the ch unit is based on. It is entirely dependent on the typeface, and can be arbitrary.

The closest is U+2007 FIGURE SPACE, which is suggested to have the same width as a digit (not necessarily the digit zero), but again this depends entirely on the typeface having equal-width digits, which not all of them do.